# How to place custom Jupyter kernels inside virtual environment?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a custom Jupyter kernel which runs IPython using a custom IPython profile which uses a matplotlib stylesheet.

I know to run this successfully normally I would put:

- The matplotlib stylesheet in ~/.config/matplotlib/stylelib/
- The IPython profile in ~/.ipython/
- The kernel json in ~/.jupyter/kernels/my_kernel/

But I am doing this as part of larger program which runs in a virtualenv, and if I put the things as above then any notebook server running on the computer will be able to see the custom kernels, even if it is running outside the venv. I don't what this because I don't want my program to interfere with other notebooks on the computer.

I think what I need to do is put the things above somewhere equivalent inside the venv but I can't figure out where they should go. Doe anyone know where they would go? Or is this just a thing IPython/Jupiter can't/won't do?

It's probably worth mentioning that in the case of the stylesheet for example I don't want to just put it in the working directory of my program (which is one option matplotlib offers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put kernelspecs in `VIRTUAL_ENV/share/jupyter/kernels/` and they will be made available if the notebook server is running in that env. In general, `<sys.prefix>/share/jupyter/kernels` is included in the path to look for kernelspecs.

You can see the various locations Jupyter will look, you can see the output of `jupyter --paths`:

$ jupyter --paths

```
config:
    /Users/you/.jupyter
    /Users/you/env/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/you/Library/Jupyter
    /Users/you/env/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/you/Library/Jupyter/runtime
```

Kernelspecs are considered [data files](https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/system.html#data-files), and will be found in any of those directories listed under `data:`, in a `kernels` subdirectory, e.g. `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I knew it was something like that but couldn't work out the exact directory. `jupyter --paths` and the fact that kernelspecs count as data files was what I was missing.