# Why is creating a new IPython kernel recommended when running Jupyter in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, python-venv

On my latest clean install, I elected to run Jupyter in it's own virtual environment.

I just made a new venv, installed Jupyter and it's dependencies into it, and then ran `jupyter lab` from the activated venv. Everything worked fine, and it wasn't until later when I was reading up on some other stuff I noticed the recommended practice is usually to install a new IPython kernel into the environment and use that.

See here:https://medium.com/@eleroy/jupyter-notebook-in-a-virtual-environment-virtualenv-8f3c3448247

And here: https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/

My install seems to work fine, and this virtual environment is the only place where I have Jupyter/IPython installed. What is the difference between the way I'm running and the methods suggested in these articles?

Edited to address comments:

Method from links:

1. Create venv
2. Install dependencies into venv
3. Install new IPython kernel into venv
4. Fire up Jupyter and select newly created IPython kernel for notebooks.

My method:

1. Create venv
2. Install Jupyter into venv
3. Install dependencies into venv
4. Fire up Jupyter from inside activated venv. Only a single kernel is available.

Comment: Not the answer of "why virtual" but here is a more of a "how to virtual": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282376/how-to-place-custom-jupyter-kernels-inside-virtual-environment

Comment: Could you state in a table or with an unnumbered list what 1) Angelo Basile did in his links and 2) what you did in your set-up? (Would like it down to the command prompts & dir structures) That seems to be what you want in "What is the difference between the way I'm running and the methods suggested." Without this detail, you're forcing the readers to guess as to what you did.

Comment: @rajah9 added, hopefully that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the kernel otherwise you will be using some global kernel. See the following example, following your steps:

1. Create venv
2. Install Jupyter into venv
3. Install dependencies into venv
4. Fire up Jupyter from inside activated venv. Only a single kernel is available. Since, in my machine there is a global python 3.8 installation the kernel is running that version not the one from the virtual environment:

[image]

If you actually install the kernel, as stated in the [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#) then you have the expected behaviour:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This [Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) site had a decent explanation of the "why virtual" question. Here's a salient quote:

> At its core, the main purpose of Python virtual environments is to
>   create an isolated environment for Python projects. This means that
>   each project can have its own dependencies, regardless of what
>   dependencies every other project has.

--EDIT--
(Since the OP added the steps, side-by-side, the answer is being updated to provided a side-by-side comparison.)

Because Basile created the virtual environment first, you would be able to create different dependency stacks for a new Python project or new Jupyter notebook.

(Speculation here, since I have not gone through the OP's steps:) Since the OP's method placed the Jupyter notebook inside the virtual environment, you'll be limited to that single set of dependencies.

Comment: I wasn't asking about virtual environments, I was asking why a new kernel is recommended when using a virtual environment.

Comment: So that you can load the specific dependencies by project.

Comment: That's not necessary to load specific dependencies. That's the virtual environment. I'm using a virtual environment and understand their use. Please read my original question.